# Python list mathematical operation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have list named `money` and I am trying to find the total amount. Is there a way to do it like that as shown in the expected output:

```
money = [
    ("+", 0,0,0,0),
    ("1", 0,0,0,1),
    ("2", 0,0,1,0),
    ("/", 0,0,1,1),
    ("4", 0,1,0,0)]

my_money= [[0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

expected output:

```
total = 2+4/1
total = 6
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier if `money` was a dict... Do you have control over it (i.e. change it)?

Comment: yes, i have .  but not over my_money

Comment: I don't quite understand how the `money` list relates to the expected output. How do you get from `+ 1 2 / 4` to `2+4/1`? What is the meaning of the 0s and 1s? What is `my_money`?

Comment: Please clarify your post. It's not clear what the relation is between your data and the result.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `my_money`'s elements are binary encoding of the `money` list's elements' indexes. So it seems that the other values in the `money` list are redundant and the elements can be indexed directly with binary encoding:

```py
for l in my_money:
    index = int(''.join(str(x) for x in l), 2)
    print(money[index][0], end=' ')
```

Gives:

```
2 + 4 / 1
```

---

If you have control over `money` and can change its structure it would help you alot. Anyway, you can pre-process the current `money` to a more appropriate structure - a dict:

```py
money_dict = {t[1:]: t[0] for t in money}
```

Now `money_dict` looks like this:

```
money_dict = {
    (0,0,0,0): '+',
    (0,0,0,1): '1',
    (0,0,1,0): '2',
    (0,0,1,1): '/',
    (0,1,0,0): '4'}
```

So now the task is much easier:

```py
my_money= [[0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
print(*(money_dict[tuple(l)] for l in my_money))
```

which gives:

```
2 + 4 / 1
```

---

The above is `O(n)` where `n = len(my_money)`. You can still do it with the original `money` but the best you can do is `O(n*m)` where `m = len(money)`:

```py
for l in my_money:
    for t in money:
        if t[1:] == tuple(l):
            print(t[0], end=' ')
            break
```